# Separate git repositories for React development

Tags: git, reactjs

I have created a React project using `create-react-app` for my front-end team.
The team is divided into 2 in terms of functionality. How can each team have their own git repository with their own functionality and the final app is combined in the end?
We tried `submodules` but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Why do they need their own repository? Just makes things harder to maintain, if the functionallity is meant to be put together anyway - keep it together. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: What means _did not work as expected?_. You want some other functionalities or you could not configure it?

Comment: Also you must note that git does not combine two projects. It just manage combination of one file which is modified at the same time by two people...

Comment: @BonjeFir we are getting a merge conflict when doing `git submodule update`

Comment: Our teams are creating different components not related to each other, so how can we implement the this [git model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Should we use feature branches derived from develop branch for each team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it is useful to clear usage of submodules in git. According to official git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use
>   another project from within it.

Q: If your sub-projects individually are meaningful, you must use submodules (as an example each part is a library/project which can uses in several projects). *I think this is not your case!*

What this [link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) noted is a suggestion to use as workflow. Before using that it is useful to clear the branch usage in git. For an in detailed description you can read [this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is), but your case is this: Every team(even every body) can develop its code on a branch and save its changes as sequential commits on that. At last you can merge that branch to another one to apply all changes on target branch. So in your case each develop team can use its own branch(example `frontend_1`, `frontend_2` or `backend` branches). Finally they can merge their branches on `master` to integrate their code. All of these done in a single repository(without submodules).

**Note:** If during the development one file modified at the same time in two different locations, it cause conflict and must resolve manually. This is not respect to submodules or workflow. This may occur on `pull`, `rebase` or even `merge` process.